# Why divide by $N^2$ for Covariance?

Tags: covariance, variance, correlation

I am trying to understand Covariance intuitively. Below is the general formula

$$
\mathrm{Cov}(X,Y) = \dfrac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^N(x_i - \overline{x})(y_i - \overline{y})}{N} \tag{1}
$$

There is another formula as per [this](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Yuli_Zhang/publication/261496020_Some_new_deformation_formulas_about_variance_and_covariance/links/54eda4c80cf25da9f7f1274e/Some-new-deformation-formulas-about-variance-and-covariance.pdf) paper which I am not sure if widely known.

$$
\mathrm{Cov}(X,Y) = \dfrac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^N\sum\limits_{j=i+1}^N(x_i-x_j)(y_i - y_j)}{N^2} \tag{2}
$$

**Situation**

> I am starting from (2) and trying to end up with (1). I am done with visualizing numerator of (2), but stuck with why $N^2$ in denominator.

**Why I start with (2)?**
{2} is easier to understand intuitively via a wonderful analogy as answered in stack exchange [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/18058/how-would-you-explain-covariance-to-someone-who-understands-only-the-mean).

The numerator in {2} gives the total rectangles which we could color and see the underlying measure in a visual sense. What I am failing to understand is,

**Question:**

> Why divide by $N^2$? What is its purpose? Is it to cancel out the units of X and Y, and make the measure unitless? Or is it because it is in some way the probability function $p(x_i,x_j,y_i,y_j)$ with assumed uniform distribution $\dfrac{1}{N^2}$?

**Update - My hypothesis:**
But needs clarity and confirmation from experts. 
Imagine the numerator of {2} as $h(x,y)$. What we are actually interested is the **expected value of $h(x,y)$**. In that sense,

$$
E[h(x,y)] = \sum\limits_{i=1}^N\sum\limits_{j=i+1}^N(x_i-x_j)(y_i - y_j)p(x_i,y_i)  \tag{3}
$$

where $p(x_i,y_i)$ is probability mass function for $h(x,y)$. Assuming **equal probability for all $(x_i,y_i)$**, then for $N^2$ possible pairs of $(x_i,y_i)$

$$
p(x_i,y_i) = \dfrac{1}{N^2}  \tag{4}
$$

This also seemingly leads to a trap. If $p(x_i,y_i) = \dfrac{1}{N^2}$, then it also means

$$
p(x_i,y_i) = \dfrac{1}{N}\dfrac{1}{N} = p(x_i)p(y_i)  \tag{5}
$$

leading to say, X and Y are independent???

Comment: To get the same answer as (1)?

Comment: try to explode the values  $\bar{x}$ and $\bar{y}$ as $\frac{\sum x_j}{N}$ and $\frac{\sum y_j}{N}$ then observe that you gain a $N$ on the denominator

Comment: @ALG I am going from {2} to {1}, not otherway round. If you start at {1}, there is no intuition why did we choose mean in the formula. I wanted to start from scratch, and organically end up using mean as in {1}, so I start from {2}, but stuck at why $N^2$. Every step I want to be justified why it is there.

Comment: Equation {2}'s numerator is equal to what the intuitive answer given [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/18058/how-would-you-explain-covariance-to-someone-who-understands-only-the-mean) points to. Sadly the [author](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/919/whuber) did not finish explaining the numerical part $\dfrac{1}{N^2}$

Comment: We divide by $N^2$ so that if you picked more and more points from the same distribution, the covariance wouldn't keep increasing. We want the answer to converge to something that depends only on the distribution, not on the number of points we picked.

Comment: @Rahul  If you observe carefully, the no of "rectangles" in the numerator of {2} is not $N^2$, but $\dfrac{N(N-1)}{2}$, so a better candidate to make it independent of count of samples would be dividing by $\dfrac{N(N-1)}{2}$, so why $N^2$ is used instead?